# Is there a name for this type of vector norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, inner-products

In the case of the $\mathcal{l}_2$ norm we have,

$$||\mathbf{x}||_2^2=\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}.$$

I was wondering if there was a type of norm that had a linear operation embedded in it, like this,

$$||\mathbf{x}||^2_A=\mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x},$$

where A is a real matrix.

Comment: Many call it $A$ norm. But that is quite ambiguous. Notice that it is only a norm if the symmetric part of $A$ is positive definite!

Comment: @user251257 Can you give a reference like a book or link? Google is not helping.

Comment: For that name? Try introductory texts on linear algebra, in particular on inner product and bilinear form.  I know that name only in context of cg method (conjugate gradient).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's only a norm if $A$ is positive definite. If $A$ is positive definite, then I would call what you describe "the $A$ norm".

Comment: Actually it must be positive *definite*.

Comment: So having an inner product defined as $<x,y>_A=x^T A y$ with A being positive definite allows me to define the norm $||x||^2_A = x^T A x$? @5xum

Comment: @layn Precisely. And the resulting space is isomorphic to the $\ell_2$ space.

Comment: @5xum So the main difference in the end is that distances in the new A-norm space when compared to $\mathcal{l}_2$ space are different, but still recuperable due to the isomorphism.

Comment: @layn Exactly. $ $

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is usually associated with a [bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form), moreover we say:

A scalarproduct on a real vector space $V$ (induced by a bilinear form $B$)  is a symmetric, non-degenerated, positive definite bilinear form. A scalarproduct then induces a norm.

If we are dealing with a finite dimensional real vector space, we can then also write

$$
B(x,x)=<x,x>_B=x^tBx
$$

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can say is that $||\cdot||_A$ is a norm induced by an inner product.

(Not all norms are like that.)

The matrix $A$ is the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) of that inner product with respect to the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^n$ (provided $A$ is positive definite).